# Powershell to change sample rate CSV file from data logger

Tags: powershell

I have csv data from a datalogger that collected the info every second rather than every 15minutes and I made a script to export every 900th entry. The script works for smaller csv files (up to 80mb). But I have one file at 3.6GB, and it doesn't work.

I looked online and found better methods to increase the speed (don't have .net, and haven't been able to get stream.reader to work).

Here is the script:

```
$file = Import-Csv z:\csv\input_file.csv -Header A,B,C,D,E,F
 $counter = 0
 ForEach ($item in $file) 
 {
$counter++
 If($counter -lt 900)
 {
}
Else{
 Write-Output “$item” | Out-File "z:\csv\output_file.csv" -Append
$counter=0
 }
}
```

Any ideas/optimizations are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip reading it as a CSV, and just read it as text. Then loop through iterating by 900 at a time, and output those lines.

```
$file = Get-Content z:\csv\input_file.csv -ReadCount 1000
For($i=0; $i -le $file.count;$i=$i+900){
    $file[$i] | Add-Content z:\csv\output_file.csv
}
```

I'm sure there are probably other optimizations that could be made, but that's a simple way to speed things up.

**Edit:** Ok, so `-ReadCount` behaves a little differently than I had anticipated. When set to a number other than 0 or 1 it creates an array of arrays of strings. So, basically `[array[string[]]]`, at which point there's two options here... either use `-ReadCount 0` to read the entire file at once, or better yet read in 900 lines at a time and output only the first of each set, and pass that directly down the pipe to `Set-Content`.

```
Get-Content z:\csv\input_file.csv -ReadCount 900 | %{$_[0]} | Set-Content z:\csv\output_file.csv
```

So that will read the file into memory 900 lines at a time, and then pass only the first line from each series down the pipe, and output that to the output file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this but it exported every row up to 2001 and didn't take only the 900th entry.

Comment: Hm, maybe I misused `-ReadCount`. I'll look into that, but you can try the same thing without `-Readcount 1000` and that should work.